# Allign view in relativelayout to borders

Tags: android, layout, view, android-relativelayout

Is there a way to layout a view inside a relativelayout next to a border.

I have the following layout(Reduced test case) and I would like to have the image moved as far to the right as possible, so it aligns with the right border. Is there any layout way to do that?

```
<RelativeLayout android:background="#ff0000" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<EditText android:layout_width='200dp' 
android:layout_height='wrap_content' 
android:text='First line' 
android:id='@+id/first' />

<ImageView android:src='@drawable/test_grid16x16' 
android:layout_width="16dp" 
android:layout_height="16dp"
android:layout_toRightOf ='@id/first'/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: fill_parent is deprecated, use match_parent instead.

Comment: fill_parent **isn't** deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a RelativeLayout, childen can set these attributes to true to be aligned to their container's borders: **alignParentTop**, **alignParentBottom**, **alignParentLeft**, and **alignParentRight**; and can be combined.

In your case: add alignParentRight="true" to your ImageView.

I'd also move this:

```
android:layout_toRightOf ="@id/first"
```

to

```
android:layout_toLeftOf ="@id/myImage"
```

in you EditText instead of in your ImageView.

Because now your ImageView rules the scene, and the EditText must be placed accordingly (also, you have to declare the EditText AFTER the ImageView, or the ImageView's id still isn't assigned).

Let's say that now it is the EditText that has to be placed "near to" (toLeftOf) the ImageView, after the ImageView has been created and placed.

In other words, this is what you want:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="#ff0000" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/test_grid16x16" 
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="16dp" 
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:alignParentRight="true"
    />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf ="@id/myImage"
        android:text="First line" 
        android:id="@+id/first"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that, here and there, you put a single quotation mark ('), instead of a doble quotation mark (").

Comment: Thanks. I made it work using your example. The key is that you can't use both android:layout_toRightOf and layout_alignParentRight.

Comment: Sorry! my Typo... I didn't correct toLeftOf in EditText - I was sure I did - doing it now (I said it in my description and then forgot to modify the layout!!)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code-

```
<RelativeLayout android:background="#ff0000" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<EditText android:layout_width="200dp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/myimg"  
android:text="First line"
android:id="@+id/first" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/myimg"
android:src="@drawable/test_grid16x16" 
android:layout_width="16dp" 
android:layout_height="16dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this works.

Or In your code add- `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` in `ImageView`.

And `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` in `EditText`.

Use **"** in android attributes instead of **'**

Comment: It won't work. Unless you **swap the definition of the ImageView and the EditText**. For the simple reason that **the EditText is referring the ImageView's id, while this still hasn't been created**.

Comment: And this: toLeftOf="@+id/myimg" should really be written **toLeftOf="@id/myimg"** (without the **plus**). The plus is only needed to CREATE a new id.

Comment: thats why no need to swap.

Comment: By the way, formatting code is universally condidered a best practice... ;)